# JQuery .slideToggle isn't smooth on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a inner table inside an outer table which contains data from the outer. I've decided to hide it and show it only the a user presses 'Expand' button. I've done it using JQuery slideToggle function like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.partTableContent').hide();
  $('.expandButton').click(function() {
    // .parent() selects the A tag, .next() selects the P tag
    $(this).closest('tr').next(' tr').find('table').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

Html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="partsTable">

  <tr>

    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">
      <button class="expandButton">Expand button</button>
    </td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
    <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="partTableContent">
        <tr>
          <td> Test1 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Test2 </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

But the animation of this action leaves much to be desired. The hidden contents pop-up instansly without any smooth animation. I've tried to use 'slow' inside .slideToggle and change the width of the table. But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: try with the easing parameter, `.slideToggle(200, 'linear');`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work means what exactly is not working? Animation itself or smooth effect?

Comment: The smooth effect

Comment: Try with more milliseconds? Maybe 600?

Comment: I've tried everything with any params...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your inner table inside a `<div>` and give the class to that div `class="partTableContent"`. See if the following code works:

```
<table class="partsTable">

    <tr>

        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">
            <button class="expandButton">Expand button</button>
        </td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
        <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="partTableContent">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Test1 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Test2 </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Then, change

```
$(this).closest('tr').next(' tr').find('table').slideToggle(200);
```

to

```
$('.partTableContent').slideToggle(200);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/vtfjdjL1/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but here's the thing:
I have a lot of "partsTable"'s and this query is like that solely because it "slides" only a particular sub-table by finding next tr tag inside a particular table

Comment: For that still you can  use `$(this).closest('tr').next(' tr').find('div.partTableContent').slideToggle(200);`